# Read extra javascript code from file on the fly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm looking to create an app in nodejs that is extensible with a separate javascript file.
The idea is that I create an app that has a GUI in which you can type commands but the commands are defined in a separate file not contained in the source structure so that a user can create their own commands, making it essentially extensible. For anyone who used it, this is the same as the Ubiquity addon for firefox from back in 2008.

I have done this already in java using Rhino but Rhino can't handle async calls and I want the commands to be able to call APIs.

My question is if within a node js app, you can have a line that does something to the effect of

```
let externalObject = read(file.js);    // contains the definition for SomeObject;
let foo = new externalObject.SomeObject();
foo.someFunctionFromFileJs();
```

Comment: If you already know the file location you can use `require`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `require()` inside a loader function and load your extension. However this would have to be on the server side. The function could be triggered by some API endpoint, would load the module on the server, and perhaps other end points would allow for interaction with it.

index.js

```js
//...

const loadExtension = ()=>{
  const extension = require('./extension');
  return extension;
}

myExtension = loadExtension();

console.log(myExtension.add(2, 5)); //output: 7
console.log(myExtension.multiply(2, 5)); //output: 10
```

extension.js

```js
const add = (a, b) => a+b;
const multiply = (a, b) => a*b;

module.exports = {add, multiply}
```

Comment: instead of `loadExtension` you can just do `const myExtension = require('./extension');`

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks.